# Python: optimize big job that appends 200,000 files

Tags: python

I have the following job in python that appends 200,000 files together (expected volume as 13GB). I'm running this on my laptop.
As it's going quite slowly (I'd say 5 files a second), I'd like to make sure it is optimized.
Is there any way I can improve this job in performance?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from xml.dom import minidom
import os

f=open('C:\\temp\\temp.xml','w')
f.write("")
f.close();

counter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\Users\username\Desktop\mydata"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xml"):

            xmldoc = minidom.parse(os.path.join(root, file))
            article = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('article').item(0)
            with open("C:\\temp\\temp.xml", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(article.toxml('utf-8'))
            counter+=1
            print(counter)
```

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't open and close filehandles to `"C:\\temp\\temp.xml"` over and over again.

Comment: A side note, your initial `f=open('C:\\temp\\temp.xml','w')` is unnecessary for creation of the file. Opening with "a" when the file does not exist will create it.

Comment: @JackManey so I move the open statement at the begging of the file and then close it once at the very end, correct?
Jan-PhilipGehrcke I'm trying to reset the file if it already exists. Is it not the right way?

Comment: Yep. In fact, you can delete the `f.write("")`, move the `f.close()` to the end (and leave off the semicolon), remove `with open(...) as myfile`, and dedent the next line while changing `myfile` to `f`.

Comment: You can "reset" it like this, yes. However, a much better approach is to wrap your entire file processing in a context manager `with open('C:\\temp\\temp.xml','w') as f:` and then only invoke `write()` within your loop. No need to re-open and close in between.

Comment: thanks for the help! Good learning

Comment: Maybe what you want is `fileinput.input` ?

Comment: At 5 files per second I don't think the extra opening and closing calls are your problem. It's the xml parsing and processing is which is taking time. I would distribute the 200,000 files to multiple computers and then combine the results at the end which should result in near linear speed-up.

Comment: You're optimizing, so I guess the first question to ask is ['Have you profiled your code?'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

Answer (score 1):

The huge bottleneck of my code was the `minidom` library. I switched to `lxml` and the code got (seriously) 100x faster